# How do I debug a C# console app on OSX with monodevelop

Tags: c#, macos, debugging, console-application, monodevelop

so I'm trying to debug a C# console app in MonoDevelop on OSX.  If I run the application, it executes (mostly) outputting stuff to the terminal window (ala console.writeline).

The problem is, if I try to 'Run->Start Debugging', a terminal window opens, dumps the text below, and just sits there staring at me all cold and blank.

```
Last login: Fri Apr  4 17:31:25 on ttys001
    clear; cd "/Users/<path stuff>/bin/Debug"; "/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/bin/mono"  --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49703 
    "/Users/<path stuff>/bin/Debug/Gen.exe" ; 
    echo; 
    read -p 'Press any key to continue...' -n1; 
    exit
        Eve:~ N$ clear; cd "/Users/<path stuff>/bin/Debug"; "/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/bin/mono"  --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49703 
    "/Users/<path stuff>/bin/Debug/Gen.exe" ; 
    echo; 
    read -p 'Press any key to continue...' -n1; 
    exit
```

I notice the cursor is a block rather than a line.  I'm otherwise at a loss.

I'm pretty new to OSX so this terminal stuff is a bit unfamiliar, but it looks like it's trying to execute the debugger on my bin, but it ain't working.  No breakpoints get hit, no write lines appear, nothing but an empty terminal window.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: what version of monodevelop?

Comment: I'm not near my lappy, but if the terminal window is correct (as above) 2.10.11.  I will double check when I get home.

Comment: that is the version of mono (which btw is really old, but I guess you can't do anything about it), not monodevelop

Comment: apologies, mondevelop version is 4.0.1

Comment: please upgrade to monodevelop 4.2.x (in Mac it's called Xamarin Studio)